# Adding Basic Auth header with VLC

Tags: http, vlc

I'm trying to play a HTTP streaming that requires basic auth in order to transcode it. When running the following command

```
vlc "http://username:password@ip_address/api/holographic/stream/live_high.mp4?holo=true&pv=true&mic=true&loopback=true"
```

the VLC media player opens and i have to manually enter username and password. Is there a way to pass a HTTP header so i can perform this action programmatically without a GUI ?

My header would be

```
"Authorization: Basic username:password"
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Regrettably, this is not supported with current versions of VLC.